# pickle.load gives TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, typeerror, pickle

I have a class instance called bot that I am trying to save as a .pkl object. I can successfully save it but when I try to load it again I get a TypeError. I know this is not very descriptive but I am trying to figure out how to look for the issue since the error traceback is giving me no directions. Here's a short snippet of all I can see:

```
bot_path = "mybot.pkl"
bot.save_state(bot_path)
loaded_bot = pickle.load(open(bot_path, 'rb'))
```

Output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 3
----> 3 loaded_bot = pickle.load(open(bot_path, 'rb'))

TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this or how to be able to investigate further what the issue could be?

Comment: Check your `loaded_bot` keyword, find if is there any method named it. This error occurs because of loaded_bot currently is a method name, and you are trying assign value to it with `=`

Comment: Almost impossible to assess without any information about the `bot` object.

Answer (score 2):

After much testing, I figured it out. I redefined the methods
__str__() and __dict__() in another object that was being initialized inside the bot class. Changing the method names to to_str(self) and to_dict(self) solved the issue. I am still confused by this but it works now. Anyways, hope this helps someone if they run into the same issue!

Original code:

```
import pickle

class Trade():
    def __init__(self, id=0, name=""):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __dict__(self):
        return {"id": self.id, "name": self.name}

    def __str__(self):
        return "id: {}, name: {}".format(self.id, self.name)


class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.trades = []

    def add_trade(self, trade):
        self.trades.append(trade)


bot = Bot()
trade = Trade(1, "trade1")
bot.add_trade(trade)
with open("bot.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(bot, f)
f.close()
loaded_bot = pickle.load(open("bot.pkl", "rb"))
```

Which returns:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 27
     25     pickle.dump(bot, f)
     26 f.close()
---> 27 loaded_bot = pickle.load(open("bot.pkl", "rb"))

TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment
```

However, changing it to this makes it work:

```
class Trade():
    def __init__(self, id=0, name=""):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def to_dict(self):
        return {"id": self.id, "name": self.name}

    def to_str(self):
        return "id: {}, name: {}".format(self.id, self.name)


class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.trades = []

    def add_trade(self, trade):
        self.trades.append(trade)


bot = Bot()
trade = Trade(1, "trade1")
bot.add_trade(trade)
with open("bot.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(bot, f)
f.close()
loaded_bot = pickle.load(open("bot.pkl", "rb"))
```

Comment: Then surely there would have been more information in the traceback, not just a single line?

Comment: @JohnGordon it is not, try it yourself (I just updated it with a sample code snippet). I am also surprised by it.